# fraction simplication, resolution with one variable

Tags: fractions

I'm having some problems to understand a simplification and I know the correct answer but I'd like to understand why my method is wrong or what rule I'm breaking.

I have an equation like the following:

$$Fr \cdot \left( \frac1{Sr} + \frac1{Sp} \right) = \frac{Ft}{Sp}$$

Where the variable I'm looking for is $Fr$. My tendency was to do:

$$ Fr = \frac{Ft}{Sp} \cdot  ( Sr + Sp ) $$

But it seems to be wrong, I should have do:

$$ Ft  \cdot \left( \frac{Sp + Sr}{Sr \cdot Sp} \right) = \frac{Ft}{Sp} $$

and then:

$$ Ft = \frac{Sr \cdot Sp \cdot Ft}{Sp + Sr} $$

Why I can not simply pass & inverse the fraction to the other side? Thanks so much!!

Comment: Because $\frac{1}{Sr}+\frac{1}{Sp}\neq \frac{1}{Sr+Sp}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because

$$ \frac1a + \frac1b \neq \frac1{a+b} $$

This is already the case for $a=b=1$, where one the left side you get $2$ and on the right side you get $\frac12$.